# How to commit on master branch DB related code?

Tags: sql, database, git, github, version-control

What is the best practice for commiting DB related code on master branch? Is it OK to be incremental?

Let's say, in the first commit on master branch, there is version 1.0, with all create dbo, alter, ... insert scripts and so on.
On the second commit, there is only one script for all developers work (appended), it is re-runable, tested, staged, and it should be ok to go in production.

Is it ok to put it on master in order to satisfied best practice for master branch that "every commit on master branch should be production equal". In my case it is definitely not; the first commit, and the second one could reproduce production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to make sure that each commits include:

- a script able to build the DB completely
- a script which can modify the DB built from previous commit

That way:

- someone starting from scratch with the latest commit can use the first script to get a fully functional DB
- someone starting from a few commit back and updating to the latest commit can apply the incremental scripts from previous commits in order to upgrade the DB.

Comment: I thinks the same. To have INIT folder, and release folder(s). INIT folder must not be altered from release to release.